# Can a UICollectionView and UITableView work in a single ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am trying to implement a UITableView and a UICollectionView (25 cells with buttons) in a single ViewController, is this possible.

What I am looking for, is when I tap on the button inside the cell, it will add the button name to the TableView.

If anyone knows of any examples somewhere or any information. I would be greatful.

Comment: It is possible to do that. But you need to be more precise on how you want to do it.

Comment: I am a little confused. Can you expand on what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it. Just make sure that your `ViewController` implements both `UICollectionViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDataSource`. You will also need a `UICollectionViewDelegate` in order to detect when a cell is tapped.

On how to implement `UICollectionView` you can see here: https://www.raywenderlich.com/78550/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-1